# List objects returns files that the console shows don't exist

Tags: amazon-s3

[`ListObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjects) on a specific directory is returning a bunch of files. Most of the time the returned files exist, but sometimes some of the files it claims exist don't seem to be there. Copying those files returns an error:

> NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist. status code: 404, request id: ###, host id: ###

After seeing this error for a while I decided to turn on versioning and sure enough the version history shows that the file whose copy results in a 404 is shown in the console as having been deleted 10 minutes before the listing and the copy. Is it possible s3 can be 10 minutes behind in noticing the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual, but it is possible.

> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all regions.
>
> ...
>
> - A process deletes an existing object and immediately attempts to read it. Until the deletion is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might return the deleted data.
> - A process deletes an existing object and immediately lists keys within its bucket. Until the deletion is fully propagated, Amazon S3 might list the deleted object.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

Comment: "A process deletes an existing object and immediately lists keys..." sounds closest to my situation, but I'm super confused because (1) this started happening very suddenly and (2) the files that it's showing were deleted 10 minutes ago which doesn't seem "immediate". Is there something I can ask AWS to do for our bucket to prevent this?

Comment: It's not a common problem.  It's also possible that this is a console-only issue, and requests to the API would not be affected.  AWS does not discuss a lot of "internals" publicly but it is readily apparent that the console is not rendered by S3 but actually a separate service that talks to S3 using the same APIs as the SDKs (see your bucket logs for clear evidence of this) and the console *might* be doing some kind of "optimization" that causes the listing to be cached when it should not be.